# $STRING1 != "${STRING1/substr/}" in Linux

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting, string, suse

I have one string and I want to check if it contains the sub-string or not. So I am using this command. Below is the Linux shell script. I just want to know how the condition present in if statement works?

```
STRING1='This string contains substring.'
if [[ $STRING1 != "${STRING1/substr/}" ]]; then
  echo "Substring is present"
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

That's a convoluted and ksh-specific (though now supported by a few other shells) way to write the standard:

```
case $STRING1 in
   *substr*) echo Substring is present
esac
```

Or ksh-specific:

```
if [[ $STRING1 = *substr* ]]; then
  echo Substring is present
fi
```

`${var/pattern/replacement}` is a ksh parameter expansion operator that expands to the value of `$var` where the first occurrence of `pattern` has been replaced with `replacement`.

So `${STRING1/substr/}` is `$STRING1` with the first occurrence of `substr` replaced with nothing, so removed.

`[[ string = pattern ]]` and `[[ string != pattern ]]` are another ksh specific construct that matches string against a pattern. When the pattern is quoted, it is taken literally, so `[[ string = "string" ]]` is an equality operator (and inequality with `!=`).

So the `[[ $STRING1 != "${STRING1/substr/}" ]]` command returns true if the expansion of `$STRING1` and `${STRING!/substr/}` yield different strings, which can only happen if there was at least one occurrence of `substr` within `$STRING1`, so it's a way to check that `$STRING1` contains `substr`.

While neither `[[...]]` nor `${var/pattern/replacement}` are standard `sh` syntax, the `[` command and the `${var#pattern}` operator (that latter one also coming from ksh) are standard. So you sometimes see code like:

```
if [ "$STRING1" != "${STRING1#*substr*}" ]; then
  echo Substring is present
fi
```

Which is a standard (though not Bourne) way to check that a variable contains a substring, but again is convoluted and has no advantage over the obvious `case` statement approach.

Answer (score 1):

> check if it contains the sub-string

Seems simpler to execute

```
[ -z "${s##*substr*}" ] && echo Substring is present
```

The result of the expansion `${…}` is null (zero length) if the `substr` is present.

---

> ... how the condition present in if statement works?
>   The

```
if [[ $STRING1 != "${STRING1/substr/}" ]]; then
```

Is comparing two strings, the original unmodified and the same string with `substr` removed (`/substr/}`). If they are different (`!=`), the original string contained `substr`.